# Doctrine is generating "DEFAULT NULL" columns, even nullable=false is specified

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

We migrated the configuration from yml to annotations. In the best case if we do `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` there are no modifications. But now doctrine generates SQL "DEFAULT NULL" on all existing not nullable columns.

We tried to set explicitly nullable=false. And also we tried to move this column property from embeddable to main entity. Nothing works properly.

Table already existing. If we have this annotation

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length="255", nullable=false)
 */
protected $firstName;
```

doctrine generates:

```
ALTER TABLE user CHANGE first_name first_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: Indeed it looks very like a bug. Which Doctrine ORM and Doctrine DBAL version are you using? And which platform? There has been a few issues with MariaDB as far I remember.

Comment: Please try to clear meta-cache before schema-update: doctrine:cache:clear-metadata

Comment: Doctrine ORM 2.6; Symfony 4.2.